common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unrecognized base64 character: [
I am trying to move some files from one salesforce org to another and as part of that I have set up an integration as given below:
List<ContentVersion> listContVer = [SELECT ContentLocation, PathOnClient, Origin, Title, VersionData, FileType FROM ContentVersion Limit 1];
Id conDocument = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:listContVer[0].Id].ContentDocumentId;
List<ContentDocumentLink> listContDoc = [SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId =: conDocument];

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:CSFileMigration/services/apexrest/ContentVersion/');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setBody('{ "ContentLocation": "S","PathOnClient": "'+listContVer[0].PathOnClient+'","Origin" : "'+listContVer[0].Origin+'","ParentId":"'+listContDoc[0].LinkedEntityId+'","Title":"'+listContVer[0].Title+'","VersionData":"'+listContVer[0].VersionData+'"}');
req.setMethod('PUT'); 
Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse response = h.send(req);
System.debug('response code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
System.debug('response body: ' + response.getBody());

And in the target org I have the following code to read the data sent through integration.
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
System.debug('requestBody--'+requestBody);

MigrateFilePrams filePrams = (MigrateFilePrams)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, MigrateFilePrams.class);
System.debug('MigrateFilePrams----'+filePrams);

//Insert ContentVersion
ContentVersion cVersion = new ContentVersion();
cVersion.ContentLocation = 'S'; //S-Document is in Salesforce. E-Document is outside of Salesforce. L-Document is on a Social Netork.
cVersion.PathOnClient = filePrams.PathOnClient;//File name with extention
cVersion.Origin = filePrams.Origin;//C-Content Origin. H-Chatter Origin.
cVersion.OwnerId = filePrams.OwnerId;//Owner of the file
cVersion.Title = filePrams.Title;//Name of the file
cVersion.VersionData = filePrams.VersionData;//File content
Insert cVersion;

The following request body is sent to the target Org:
requestBody--{ "ContentLocation": "S","PathOnClient": "ForwardedAttachment_1.txt","Origin" : "C","ParentId":"00550000003X925BBF","Title":"ForwardedAttachment_1","VersionData":"Blob[1703]"}

When I am trying to set the VersionData I am getting the following error "Unrecognized base64 character: ["
Can some one please help with this. I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here

The version data you're getting from the query (that you use to build your JSON) is literally Blob[1703] and not the real versiondata, so the attempt to decode as base64 stops when it hits that [.

Any suggestions as to how I can pass the blob value from one org to another? Or decode the data in the target org? I am not modifying the data in any way. I am hitting a dead end here.

As I've said before, +Blob ends up using Object.toString instead of Blob.toString, which means you're passing the value Blob[1703] instead of the encoded data. Instead, use EncodingUtil.base64Encode. Also, do not constructor your own JSON, as that tends to cause problems. Always use JSON.serialize instead.
req.setBody(
  JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, Object> {
      'ContentLocation' => 'S',
      'PathOnClient' => listContVer[0].PathOnClient,
      'Origin' => listContVer[0].Origin,
      'ParentId' => listContDoc[0].LinkedEntityId,
      'Title' => listContVer[0].Title,
      'VersionData' => EncodingUtil.base64Encode(listContVer[0].VersionData)
    }
  )
);


Thanks so much for the fix :) Worked like a charm.
